# Charles SSL Proxying issues on latest Android SDK and Emulator

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy

I don't know if this is related to having updated Android Build Tools since I didn't try right after but I can't seem to get Charles to work propery with SSL Proxying on Android (it was working fine before).

In a nutshell, if I enable ssl proxying on my api endpoint on Charles I get:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: Certificate expired at Wed Aug 31 10:09:00 GMT+02:00 2016 (compared to Thu Sep 01 15:18:53 GMT+02:00 2016)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:344)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
```

Of course I've checked our servers certificates (they didn't expire). I've checked the [setup](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) many times, I've tried deleting emulators (API 23 & 24) and reinstalling fresh ones, I've even tried upgrading build tools and compile sdk version to 24 and using Java 8. And I've also tried upgrading to Charles 4 and reinstalling the root certificate.

The `keytool -list -keystore`/usr/libexec/java_home`/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit` does list the Charles Certificate. (for both the 1.7 and 1.8 jdks)

Charles Root certificate is properly installed on the emulator and expires in 2044

[image]

If I disable SSL Proxying on Charles, everything works just fine again with our without Charles running.

Also, when using an emulator running API 24, the exception is slightly different:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:563)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:444)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:508)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:596)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
```

On more important thing to note, the same setup works just fine on the iOS Simulators using the same api endpoint. So this definitely has to do with Java/Android configuration.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This happens with Android 7.0 if you target API level 24. Now user added CAs are not trusted by default and each app must explicitly opt-in.

To have your app trust the Charles certificate, declare a custom network security configuration in your AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    >
```

Create the file in `res/xml/network_security_config.xml` with this configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

More info: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2016/07/changes-to-trusted-certificate.html and https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing all gradle cache folders and the project .gradle folder

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
rm -rf .gradle
```

And forcing Kotlin to use v1.0.3 instead of EAP builds and it worked back again. I don't know fully what went wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure it's working with all emulators? For me API 19 and 23 emulators work, but API 24 doesn't.